# What is the exact way of using href attibute with anchor tag when we are dealing with images?

Tags: html, image, href, anchor

I think we can use href attribute to move to a specific element in a HTML document provided that the element contain an id. I implemented the logic for paragraph. I works well. But when i use it with image it shows an error like your file could not be accessed ? How to move to a specific image in a pure HTML document using anchor tag via href attribute ?

What i tried, not working for image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    
   <head>
          <title>Using Anchor Tag for Shifting</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>

          <a href="paraone">click to go to image one</a><br>
          <a href="imageone">click to go to image two</a><br>

          
          <p id="paraone">
             Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa.
             Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione.
             È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato.
             Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.
          </p><br>
          
         <img id="imageone" src="http://fullhdpictures.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Neymar.jpg" alt="Neymer Full HD Image" width="200" height="300"><br>
          
     
          <p id="paratwo">
             Lorem Ipsum è un testo segnaposto utilizzato nel settore della tipografia e della stampa.
             Lorem Ipsum è considerato il testo segnaposto standard sin dal sedicesimo secolo, quando un anonimo tipografo prese una cassetta di caratteri e li assemblò per preparare un testo campione.
             È sopravvissuto non solo a più di cinque secoli, ma anche al passaggio alla videoimpaginazione, pervenendoci sostanzialmente inalterato.
             Fu reso popolare, negli anni ’60, con la diffusione dei fogli di caratteri trasferibili “Letraset”, che contenevano passaggi del Lorem Ipsum, e più recentemente da software di impaginazione come Aldus PageMaker, che includeva versioni del Lorem Ipsum.
          </p><br>
          
                    <img id="imagetwo" src="https://en.as.com/en/imagenes/2021/07/02/football/1625240438_032795_1625244535_sumario_grande.jpg" alt="Messi Full HD Image" width="200" height="300"><br>
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: consider adding the html tag, and also use language identifier to highligh the code

Comment: done as you suggested, thank you..